# Почему не получается добавить в url параметр page?

Tags: php

Пишу что-то вроде мини-блога и хочу реализовать счетчик страниц через параметр url.
На сайте есть ссылка с адресом, в которой уже установлен параметр page:

```
<a href="articles_page.php?page=1">Открыть список статей</a>
```

Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы даже если пользователь вручную набрал в адресной строке articles_page.php, то чтобы добавлялся параметр page со значением 1.
На странице articles_page.php в самом начале встроен php код:

```
<?php
    if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URL"], "page") === false) { //line 2
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URL"] .= "?page=1"; //line 3
    }
?>
```

Но если ввести url articles_page.php, то выдадутся ошибки:
**Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_URL in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\articles_page.php on line 2**
**Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_URL in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\articles_page.php on line 3**
**Вопрос:** почему выдаются эти ошибки, и как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: `page` надо брать из `$_GET['page']`, а не из других мест.

Comment: а в _server хранит не REQUEST_URL а REQUEST_URI. Но в любом случае, факт того, что вы добавите к этому значению `page=..` ничего для клиента не изменит, и вообще никак не повлияет на исполнение, если он конечно, хоть как-то адекватно написан.

Comment: данный редирект и через .htaccess можно добавить

Comment: @teran попробовал так: if (!isset($_GET["page"])) {$_GET["page"] = 1;}
Но ?page в ссылке не появилось

Comment: Я разобрался: надо написать if (!isset($_GET["page"])) {$_GET["page"] = 1; header("Location: articles_page.php?page=1");}

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page нужно брать из `$_GET['page']`, а не из других мест - @teran

Код, реализующий это:

```
if (!isset($_GET["page"])) {
      header("Location: articles_page.php?page=1");
}
```

Comment: остается только загадкой, зачем вам это нужно.